# My bufferedWriter is writing random characters even though my getMethod works correctly

Tags: java

I am reading in grades and writing their averaged but it keeps writing random characters.
This is what is being read in and saved:

```
            String line = in.nextLine();
            String fields[] = line.split(",");
            
            String fname = fields[0];
            String lname = fields[1];
            String id = fields[2];
            Student student = new Student(fname, lname, id);
            
            for(int i = 3; i < fields.length; i++) {
                student.addGrade(Integer.parseInt(fields[i]));
                
                }
            students.add(student);
            
        }
        in.close();
```

and this is the method:

```
  public int getAverage() {
    if(grades.size() == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    int average = 0;
    int sum=0;
    for (int i=0; i < grades.size();i++){
        
        sum += grades.get(i);               
    }
    
    return  sum/grades.size();      
}
```

I don't know where I went wrong because when I do not use the bufferedWriter and I just print them, it is correct.

```
        for(Student student : students) {
            out.write(student.getID());
            out.write(",");
            out.write(student.getAverage());
            out.write(",");
            out.write(student.getLetterGrade());
            out.newLine();
        }
        out.close();
```

Comment: "This is what is being read in and saved" you left out the writing part of the code.

Comment: Please show us the output you are getting, and the code that is doing the printing

Comment: Use `PrintWriter` and its `print()` methods instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `BufferedWriter`'s **`write(int)`** method to print the values. But you need to display the text (string) representation of the integers, and **[that's not what that method does](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#write(int)).**

What you are actually doing is printing the [`ASCII char`](https://ascii.cl/) that corresponds to the given number. For example, `write(65)` will print the character **`'A'`**.

Change these calls:

```
bw.write(student.getAverage());
```

With [**this**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#write(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int)) other ones:

**`public void write(String s,int off,int len)`**

You need to previously convert the values to `String`. For example:

```
String averageS = String.valueOf(student.getAverage());
bw.write(averageS, 0, averageS.length());
```